# Is it possible to connect to a non publicly available RDS instance from SequelPro?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a MySql AWS RDS instance inside a VPC. I was wondering if it is possible to make the RDS instance NOT publicly available, but still be able to somehow connect to the DB via SequelPro or Workbench.

Thanks!

Comment: A SSH tunnel is an option, or VPN, http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Connecting_to_a_MySQL_Server_on_a_Remote_Host

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the desired goal, do the following:

1. Create a public subent and a private one.
2. Put your database in a private subnet, disable external access
3. Create an EC2 instance in a public subnet. RDP into it. Use it in order to connect to the private RDS. (by default public and private subnets in AWS are able to communicate with each other)

This technique is called "bastion host" it's described in more details here:
http://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-bastion-host-nat-instances-vpc-peering-security/

Also the following resource could be helpful for you:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html